Type narrowing on private members results in Property does not exist on type 'never' error
When I try to use type narrowing on a private member, I get a typescript error
You can see an example below.
class Inventory {
    private book?: string;

    hasBook(): this is { book: string } {
        return !!this.book;
    }

    // Example method
    bookLength(): number | undefined {
        const hasBook = this.hasBook();
        if (hasBook) {
            // TypeScript knows that `this.book` exists here
            return this.book.length;
        } else {
            return undefined;
        }
    }
}

The line return this.book.length; will show a typescript error
Property 'book' does not exist on type 'never'.
  The intersection 'this & { book: string; }' was reduced to 'never' because property 'book' exists in multiple constituents and is private in some.

I really want to use type narrowing and avoid using null assertion or optional chaining or other workarounds.
Is there a way to get this to work that I am missing?

No, you can't do this directly. The closest I can think of is to use generics as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer (or find a suitable duplicate target). If not, what am I missing?

I ended up avoiding this scenario. The idea was an object needs to initialize, which involved several properties - and I wanted to avoid repetition or use the non null assertion (!) operator.
Apparently this is not possible in a way to my liking.
And by requiring the initialization to happen in advance, the overall codebase is simplified, as the state of the system becomes clearer.

Is there a reason for not doing this?
class Inventory {
    private book?: string;

    // Example method
    bookLength(): number | undefined {
        if (!!this.book) {
            return this.book.length;
        } else {
            return undefined;
        }
    }
}

another option would be a type predicator like so
type Book = string

class Inventory {
    private book: Book | undefined;

    hasBook(arg:unknown): arg is Book  {
        return !!arg && typeof arg === "string"
    }

    // Example method
    bookLength(): number | undefined {
        
        if (this.hasBook(this.book)) {
            return this.book.length;
        } else {
            return undefined;
        }
    }
}


The second approach seems more reasonable to me. I'll try that.
